# View.OnTouchListener stops responding after thread start

Tags: android, view, runnable, ontouchlistener

Why does the View.OntouchListener stops working after thread.start?

Here's my code:

```
public class MultiviewActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        c = getBaseContext();
        handler = new myHandler();

        final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.i("multiView", "Touch id=" + viewid);
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                super.onLongPress(e);
            }
        });
        View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewid = v.getId();
                return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        LinearLayout lay = findViewById(R.id.l1);
        lay.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

        //timer
        Runnable timerrunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!bisruning) {
                    thread = new Thread(MultiviewActivity.this);
                    thread.start();
                }
                timerhandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        timerhandler.postDelayed(timerrunnable, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        bisruning = true;
        msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        Log.i("multiView", "Running thread");
        //thread task goes here...
        msg.arg1 = 0;
        msg.arg2 = 1;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    class myHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.arg1) {
                case 0:
                    if (msg.arg2 == 1)
                        fillLayout();
                    bisruning = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as my timer ticks in (after 5s), the view stops responding to screen taps...

I know that the View is responding to taps before the thread starts because I've logged the OnDown event.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Regards

Comment: What error do you get in your `log cat` ? Are you trying to start the thread again ?. Because once you click the button to start the thread then it won't be able to start again. because thread is already running

Comment: @cantona_7 I don't get any error... the listener just stops responding... the thread is part of a timer that runs every 5 secs

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by thread runs every 5sec. Once you start the thread,it runs unless you interrupt or stop it in your onDestroy. Isn't it ?

Comment: @cantona_7 Now you've got me confused! :) shouldn't I thread.start() every 5 seconds to run a background process to colect data from somewhere? I don't interrupt or destroy any threads...

Comment: If I am not wrong, you just have to start the thread once. Thats enough. If you have more doubts, Have a look here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread

Comment: @cantona_7 You're probably right... but what if I need to run the same function (in a background thread) multiple times? what I'm doing is creating a new thread every 5 sec to do some background data colect...

Comment: What about using a handler ? You can send the message and use it to queue it.

Comment: @cantona_7 thanks, I'll give it a try